# keeping the window topmost over the start menu

Tags: c#, wpf

As I am working on screentime, I would like to block the screen after the user's allowed time gets over. My screen will be on the top after allowed time gets over.

In Microsoft family safety screentime even if the user presses windows button, start menu will appear behind the microsoft's blocking screen.  I dont know how to do the same. They've not blocked any inputs. Whatever the user does will happen behind the screen.

In my app user cannot switch to another screen. I put window.topmost = true 
in both OnLostFocus event and Deactivated event. 
Everything is working fine except the start menu case.

What is actually happening when start menu appears, which event is taking place? How can I override it?

Comment: Windows OS functions kick in on every input. You could possibly install a global hook and consume all events, but I don't know if you can override windows hotkeys that way.